# Appcelerator Alloy : How to manage the garbage collection for Android

Tags: android, ios, memory-management, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've created an app using alloy framework for both iOS and android platforms. I'm having problems with the memory. My app uses a lot of tableviews with custom rows having images.

In the iOS simulator and device it uses a lot of memory even if I close all the windows. But the good thing is that it doesn't crash. But in android it crashes more often than not. android device crashes a bit later than the emulator.

Please Help. Tell me how can I manage these memory leaks. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found a way to get through these crash problem by using the destroy() function on the windows views on back, which in turn releases most of the memory.